# AngularJS ng-click inside innerHTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs, innerhtml, angularjs-ng-click

I have this code below:

```
acrossText = acrossText + activeWordList[w].placeOrder + ". " + activeWordList[w].clue + "<button ng-click='speak()'>Speak</button> " + "<br /><br />";
document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML = acrossText;
```

However ng-click="speak()" inside innerHTML is not firing.
What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is not being compiled. You must compile it using `$compile`.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things here:

1. The `ng-click` directive has already run, so it doesn't know about your dynamically added element.
2. Dynamically adding content using innerHTML, or the like, is generally frowned upon when using angular. This looks like you are trying to re-create the functionality of a [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) I would suggest going this route, as it will give you the tools you need to fix your code.